# which is the most relevant roadmap for web frontend developer?

Tags: frontend

I try to improve my career but at this moment I think how would I start again?
What is your opinion? What is the best way to start?

i wish to know the most relevant roadmaps in frontend developer

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you must learn **HTML** and **CSS**. After doing that start learning **Javascript**. Then you can learn javascript frameworks like **React**, a free and open-source front-end JavaScript library for building user interfaces based on UI components, or **Angular**.
In beginning, I would suggest React as it has a large developer community and is also a bit easy to understand.

You will also need to learn about making API calls, so learn about **rest APIs** and **postman**.
Also, learn how to format the JSON you will get from the backend.
After that, you can work on learning **Redux**(state management tool) and typescript(a superset of JavaScript ).

*TO SUM UP THE ROADMAP :*

- HTML
- CSS
- REACT/ANGULAR
- REDUX
- API
- TYPESCRIPT (OPTIONAL)